# onNavigationItemSelected not called when using actionLayout?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

The method onNavigationItemSelected isn't being called when using actionLayout in a menu item. on ActionLayout two horizontal linear layout onClick is not called. Unable to find out how to call?

**MainActivity**

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view sendMenuItem clicks here.
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    final Intent navigationIntent = new Intent(this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);

    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.extra){
             item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.nav_rateus:

                    navigationIntent.putExtra(NavigationDrawerActivity.NAVIGATION_DRAWER_KEY, NavigationDrawerActivity.RATE_US);
                    startActivity(navigationIntent);
                    break;
                case R.id.logout:
                    //clear all data
                    clearObj();
                    AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(getApplicationContext());
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Below code for ActionLayout xml.
**logoutLayout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_rateus"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/measure_26dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/measure_26dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rateus"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rate_us"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/measure_26dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/measure_26dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logout"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/logout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Navigation Drawer menu is attached below.
**navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/extra"
    android:title=""
    app:actionLayout="@layout/logout_layout"/>
```